# appropriateness of a certain question

Tags: feature-request, subjective-questions

I would like to know whether a question about the nutritional value and effects of digesting semen, is suitable for this site.

Comment: I personally don't think so

Answer (score 4):

Probably not. Semen is not considered a food, so any discussions about its so-called "nutritional value" would likely be akin to someone asking if it is harmful to eat rocks.

There might be a curiosity and even a legitimate question, but the whole thread will **not likely** be related to legitimate issues of "Fitness & Nutrition."